# Ignore messages from anyone not on my contact list

Tags: plugins, adium

When I used Pidgin, it came with a plugin that would ignore all messages from people not on my contacts list. Is there an equivalent plugin for Adium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Menu -> Privacy Settings
- Privacy level -> **Allow only contacts on my contact list**

Answer (score 1):

All **[privacy settings](http://trac.adium.im/wiki/PrivacySettings)** for Adium are explanied in detail in the online documentation.